How do you find $\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^ay^b + x^cy^d}{x^by^a + x^dy^c}$?
I am trying to find
$$\lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^ay^b + x^cy^d}{x^by^a + x^dy^c}, a,b,c,d > 0.$$
I have tried using different paths but I always get the answer 1 so I think the limit exists and is equal to 1 but I can't find a way to prove it. I tried polar coordinates but got stuck with the cosines and sines in the denominator.

$a=c$, $b=d.$ For $y=tx$ with fixed $t>0$ the ratio is equal $t^{b-a}.$

Note that a 2D limit only exists, if it would be independent of the chosen path towards the border point.
Thus, if we could construct different paths which would provide different limit values, then we have shown that this 2D limit does not exist.
So we'd try various paths $y=mx$, with different parameter values $m$, eg. for, say $a+b>c+d$. Then
$$\frac{x^ay^b+x^cy^d}{x^by^a+x^dy^c}=\frac{x^{a+b}m^b+x^{c+d}m^d}{x^{a+b}m^a+x^{c+d}m^c}=\frac{x^{a+b-c-d}m^b+m^d}{x^{a+b-c-d}m^a+m^c}$$
Thus when considering $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ along $y=mx$, we see that this would surely need to have $x\to 0$. But
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^{a+b-c-d}m^b+m^d}{x^{a+b-c-d}m^a+m^c}=\frac{m^d}{m^c}=m^{d-c}$$
And whenever $m\neq 0,\ \pm1$ and $d\neq c$ this clearly provides different values.
(Other cases for $a,b,c,d$ can be considered quite similarily.)
Thence the assumption, that there would be a well-defined limit value for your fraction, clearly is wrong - in general:
The single case where $a=b$ and $c=d$ clearly would be an exception, as then your fraction would be 1 throughout.
Further, in case of $a+b=c+d$ the above fraction becomes
$$\frac{x^{a+b}m^b+x^{c+d}m^d}{x^{a+b}m^a+x^{c+d}m^c}=\frac{x^{a+b}m^b+x^{a+b}m^d}{x^{a+b}m^a+x^{a+b}m^c}=\frac{m^{b-c+c}+m^{a+b-c}}{m^a+m^c}=m^{b-c}$$
This shows that the subcase $a=d$ and $b=c$ likewise becomes especially.
--- rk

There is also a special case where $a=d,;b=c$.

Right you are, added.
